# Confused about Python closures

Tags: python

In "Learning Python 5th Edition" by Mark Lutz - (ISBN: 9781449355739, chapter 17: "Scopes", p. 518, sidebar: "Why You Will Care: Customizing open") - there is the following illustration:

```
import builtins

def makeopen(id):
    original = builtins.open
    def custom(*kargs, **pargs):
        print('Custom open call %r:' % id , kargs, pargs)
        return original(*kargs, **pargs)
    builtins.open = custom

makeopen('spam')
F = open('script2.py')

makeopen('eggs')
F = open('script2.py')
```

Expected output:

```
Custom open call 'spam': ('script2.py',) {}
Custom open call 'eggs': ('script2.py',) {}
```

Actual output:

```
Custom open call 'spam': ('script2.py',) {}
Custom open call 'eggs': ('script2.py',) {} 
Custom open call 'spam': ('script2.py',) {}
```

My understanding of closures is that they are supposed to return multiple copy *per-call* changeable data (ie. like instance variables in other languages).

So why is "spam" printed twice ?

I have stepped through the code with the PyCharm debugger and I still do not understand it.

Is it because the variable `original` points to an object in the built-in scope instead of an enclosing scope ?

**UPDATE:**

I think the problem was that on the 2nd call to `makeopen()`, the variable `original` recursively points to `custom()`. Maybe it was originally intended as a "feature" :/ ... but I am inclined to think it is a terrible example.

Here's a solution that works as expected:

```
import builtins

def makeopen(id):
    def custom(*kargs, **pargs):
        print('Custom open call %r:' % id , kargs, pargs)
        return builtins.open(*kargs, **pargs)
    return custom

file = 'script2.py'

f = makeopen('spam')
f(file)

g = makeopen('eggs')
g(file)
```

Note: The above solution does not actually change `builtins.open` but instead acts as a wrapper.

Comment: *"return multiple-copy data"* – what's that mean?

Comment: @deceze - I have reworded it to: "multiple copy per-call changeable data" (as used in the book). I believe it means that local variables in Python's enclosing functions are like instance variables in other languages like Java.

Comment: One way to "fix" this is to write `def makeopen(id, original=builtins.open)`. This will save the *actual* original open.

Answer (score 4):

After `makeopen('spam')`, `open` is a function which prints "spam" and then opens a file.
After `makeopen('eggs')`, `open` is now a function which prints "eggs" and then calls a function which prints "spam" and then opens a file.

You're successively wrapping the `open` function in more and more layers, ending up with:

```
print("eggs")
↳ print("spam")
  ↳ open(...)
```